# Firefox CSS transition skipping animation on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

Currently I've made this CSS transition where a div motions towards the mouse based on the cursors distance from the center of the div. When the mouse leaves the div, the div goes back to its original position. I have some JavaScript that checks for when the mouse enters and leaves the div and applies the needed styling.

On Firefox, the transition tends to skip when the mouse leaves the div and instead of slowly moving back to it's original position, it moves back instantly. This doesn't seem to happen on other browsers.

For some reason, including an arbitrary `e.target.getBoundingClientRect();` fixed the issue but I'm not sure why. What's happening here and how should I properly fix this?

```
function boxHover(e) {
    var posVector = calcHoverDist(e, 15);
    e.target.style.transitionDuration = "0.3s";
    e.target.style.transform = `scale(1.2)translate(${posVector[0]}px,${posVector[1]}px)`;
}

function boxLeave(e) {
    //e.target.getBoundingClientRect(); // brute force fix of transition bug
    e.target.style.transitionDuration = "0.8s";
    e.target.style.transform = "translate(0,0)";
}
```

[EDIT] Adding this as it's easy to miss the issue when running the code. You can reproduce the issue by waving your mouse over the div quickly in a circular motion.

https://jsfiddle.net/b0fx4ae8/2/

Comment: The transition does works.

Comment: Pardon, I realize it can be a little subtle but try waving your mouse on and off the div in a circular motion quickly. It tends to returns back to position instantly instead of transitioning. Try uncommenting that line and that issue doesn't appear..

Comment: which browser are you on? Works fine on my chrome.

Comment: I see this might be the issue. I'm on firefox. I see that the issue doesn't show up on chrome.

Comment: I've noticed that when the issue happens (only on firefox here too), it actually springs back before I really leave the box; it happens when I leave the area where the "not transformed box" would be. I can only guess that asking for `getBoundingClientRect()` forces the browser to update some cached values about the boxes bounds, putting the box into a "hover" state again.